# Sprox form with Turbogears, using Mako, only displays plain text

Tags: python, forms, mako, turbogears, sprox

I'm generating a Sprox form with Turbogears 2.1 and trying to display it in a Mako template. Here is my code:

To define the form:

```
class NewUserForm(AddRecordForm):  
    __model__ = User  
newuserform = NewUserForm(DBSession)
```

The controller definition that assigns the form and calls the template:

```
@expose('limelight.modules.users.templates.register')  
def register(self, **kw):  
    tmpl_context.register_form = newuserform  
    return dict(value=kw)
```

And the relevant template code:

```
${tmpl_context.register_form(value=value)}
```

The problem is the HTML code is displayed as plain text on the page, not rendered HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. I have to pass the variable through the the 'n' mako filter to remove any automatic filters mako applies to the html generated. So:

${tmpl_context.register_form(value=value) | n}