# Mako template encoding urls

Tags: python, mako

I have a variable whose value is html:

```
c.url = '<a href=""></a>'
```

When I display this in my mako template, the output is:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
```

What's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable's content is being filtered so that it's safe to present. `markupsafe.escape()` is being run on it.

Comment: Thanks -- How do I display text without it being filtered?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919833/turbogears-mako-form-displaying-as-plain-text/1937001#1937001